# Tried to register two views with same name

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-native-module

I know this kind of question has been asked before but they are related to third party libraries, mine is related to `requireNativeComponent`

I have created a `React Native` Component from a Native `iOS` component

Here is my `iOS` code

`CanvasView`  File

```
class CanvasView: UIView {
    
    var lines = [[CGPoint]]()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }
        
        context.setStrokeColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1))
        context.setLineWidth(10)
        context.setLineCap(.butt)
        
        lines.forEach { (line) in
            for(i,p) in line.enumerated() {
                if i == 0 {
                    context.move(to: p)
                } else {
                    context.addLine(to: p)
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        
        context.strokePath()
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        lines.append([CGPoint]())
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: nil) else {
            return
        }
        
        
        
        guard var lastLine = lines.popLast() else {return }
        lastLine.append(point)
        lines.append(lastLine)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

`Canvas.swift` File

```
import Foundation

@objc(Canvas)
class Canvas: RCTViewManager {
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    return CanvasView()
  }
  
  override class func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  
}
```

`Canvas.m` file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"


@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Canvas, RCTViewManager)
@end
```

Here is my `JS` code

```
const Canvas = requireNativeComponent('Canvas');

const App = () => {
 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Canvas style={styles.bottom} />
    </View>
  );}
```

the code works fine, but even when I do some change in my react native code and do command+s to do `fast refresh` I keep getting error saying `Tried to register two views with the same name Canvas`, but when I run `npx react-native run-ios`, the code works fine. So all in all `hot reloading or fast refresh` is not supported when I include Native component created by me even though I am not changing the native component. I can understand if I change something in iOS swift or objective c code then I need to re-run  `npx react-native run-ios` but even after no changes in `iOS` side and doing only changes in `JS` side I keep getting this error. There are not two views with same name of `Canvas` in my project. I also tried clearing `watchman`, deleting `package.json` and reinstalling `npm` modules and `pod`

Same issue happens on `android` side as well

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When fast refresh runs, this line is executed again:

```js
const Canvas = requireNativeComponent('Canvas');
```

And that's where the "Tried to register two views with same name" error comes from. There are a couple of ways to fix this.

1. Move that line to its own file and export it: `export const Canvas = requireNativeComponent('Canvas');`, and then import it where you want to use it. You'll still get the same error if you save the new file that contains this line, but you typically won't change this file so it usually won't be an issue.
2. Guard against the native component being registered (via `requireNativeComponent`) multiple times. It's a bit ugly, but you can do this by storing it in the global scope: `const Canvas = global['CanvasComponent'] || (global['CanvasComponent'] = requireNativeComponent('Canvas'));`

Answer (score 1):

**I think that issue is not from the native module. it is from register the same package two times.**

go to project root and run the below command

```
npm list
```

[image]

find the package by **ctrl+f** which you think that is creating problem like `Canvas`

remove that second package which is using the same package which is creating problem like `Canvas`

or

you can fork that package and add that package in peer dependency and use that package from your git

Comment: There is no package in npm list with Canvas because I have not integrated a third party lib using npm. I have create my own code with Native Kotlin and swift

Comment: @Pritish can you add reproducible git example so I can fix for you

Answer (score 0):

So I was having this issue until I realized that the app throwing an error on fast refresh makes perfect sense since the native UI cannot hot reload at runtime. You can update your React components since your components can remount at runtime, thereby hot-reloading.

If you try to refresh Swift or Obj-C, you are making a second instance of your data, so an error is thrown before that can happen.

The quick solution is to simply press "r" on your keyboard on the terminal where you're running the metro bundler. And you would have to do this wherever you are using a native component.